# Get Prediction Class as an integer in Weka classifier

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I used following code to implement activity recognition using weka library. I used Random Forest Classifier and this is a multi class classification problem. I use the training dataset to train a random forest model. After that, I use the model to classify test dataset which does not contain the class labels. I get double vales as the class. How can I get correct integer values? Can someone help me for that? 
And also if I cast the double values which I get to int value, I get only same integer value(0) because the predicted doubles are between 0 and 1.

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/thamali/Desktop/WekaProject/output.arff"));

            Instances trainData = new Instances(br);
            trainData.setClassIndex(trainData.numAttributes() - 1);
            br.close();
            RandomForest rf = new RandomForest();
            rf.setNumTrees(23);
            rf.setMaxDepth(18);
            rf.buildClassifier(trainData);

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/thamali/Desktop/WekaProject/testData.arff"));
            Instances testData = new Instances(br1);
            testData.setClassIndex(testData.numAttributes() - 1);

            double value=rf.classifyInstance(testData.instance(0));
            System.out.print(value);
```

Comment: `floor(value + 0.5)` ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have 12 classes and I need to have values from 1-12.